# BMC Update issue

Tags: firmware, dell-poweredge

Dell **C6100**. Bios **1.81**. BMC **1.2(2011)**

When trying to update BMC firmware using the DELL given firmware and live boot CentOS software, i am unable to stop the service `ipmi`. The update fails due to this.

I have tried:

`CentOS live boot, unable to kill process.
  - using modprobe -rf
 Ubuntu 16 LTS, unable to kill process.
  - using modprobe -rf
 WebGUI Update (megarac), image failed verification.
  - image confirmed to be true from dell
 racadm Failed to connect to IPMI.
  - IPMI user reset password and name works and confirmed. Still no access.
  - using racadm -c
 FREEDOS, Unable to run program.
  using .exe firmware from dell`

**Q. How can i update the BMC firmware when all given methods have failed?**

Comment: latest seems to be [Dell PowerEdge C6100 BMC firmware - Version 1.30](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=rd35y) the instructions seem "easy" -  you did not provide any output (screenshots?). Another Q: Why do you run it from a live CD? The instructions state "Execute corresponding Dell Update Package executable under your OS environment.".

Comment: @Zina I agree, super easy. I have tried with local OS, as well as with their given live boot OS specifically for the task of updating. The closest i can get is the error on the live boot when running the update, which begins but then stops saying that the IPMI driver must be stopped before continuing. The issue here, i cannot stop the IPMI service, through any means described above. Short of installing windows (not ideal), i have no clue what to do next, in seeking a solution.

Comment: I stll don't understand why you need  to kill the process if the instructions say to stop the service? at least you did not mention you tried it that way. I see there is also a [later version 1.33](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=9vjw6&oscode=naa&productcode=poweredge-c6100), and maybe you could try [this guy's solution with a bootable Fedora 64bit](https://stelfox.net/blog/2013/12/updating-bmc-on-dell-poweredge-c6100/)

Comment: @Zina you cannot stop the service. That is the issue. The service does not exist. But it DOES exist,under modprobe. There appears to be no way to stop it. If i could stop it, then the update would work.

Comment: @Zina ill try that fedora bootable next. thx

Comment: @Zina YES! fedora worked, I had followed that readme but with other linux distro. Using fedora, worked first time.

Comment: Interesting, but I am glad you resolved your issue. So, all you needed was to find a linux distro that worked.

Comment: @Zina apparently so. strange, but was all to do with that service.